# how can I add company logo in email in cakephp?

Tags: image, email, cakephp

I have created page for mail template and set buttons for preview template also.

I have set image path from my local machine like,

```
  src="/projectname/app/webroot/img/logo.JPG"
```

and when i preview that template it displays logo.

when using that template when i send mail image is not displayed in email.

So can anyone please tell me what could be the issuee or i am missing something like mime types?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. The email is opened in a client, what the hack would a path like "/projectname/app/webroot/img/logo.JPG" mean to that client? What is the domain?

You can either add a domain to the SRC like src="http://example.com/projectname/app/webroot/img/logo.JPG". But this won't be displayed by default, because it is a security risk.
Imagine spammers including images like src="http://example.com/feedback?id=12345" to each email, where ID is identifying each e-mail address the mail is sent to. Each client downloading this image will acknowledge the receiving of this e-mail, letting the spammers know you are reading their spam. Most e-mail clients explicitly ask you whether images referred to in the mail should be downloaded or not.

An alternative solution is to include each e-mail as an attachment to the e-mail, then you can refer to it as an "inline" image. This does no requires external connection and is less of a security risk, mostly allowed by default in clients.

I've google up a component that supposedly supports also inlining, but you might find others as well:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/CraZyLeGs/2006/12/18/swiftmailer-component-tutorial

Comment: the core CakeEmail class can also handle embedded images in html mails

Answer (score 1):

Within emails, you must use your full path, not a relative path.  To do this easily in CakePHP, use the: `FULL_BASE_URL` constant with the `HTML Helper` like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->image(
    FULL_BASE_URL . $photo['Photo']['path'].$photo['Photo']['filename']
);
?>
```

(obviously this could be done in one line, but I broke it down for ease of reading on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because when you test on your local machine, that path is fine. But if you send an email to yourself (say gmail) your browser will probably look for the image somewhere like `http://mail.google.com/gmail/projectname/app/webroot/img/logo.JPG` and will not find your image there.
So you'll need to set your image source to something like `http://localhost/projectname/app/webroot/img/logo.JPG`.

Answer (score 0):

The email client needs the absolute path to the image; use the HTML helper to attach the full base:

```
<?= $this->Html->image("logo.JPG", array('fullBase' => true)) ?>
```

Note that the `/projectname/app/webroot/img/` is not required when using the HTML helper.

Comment: This will echo a relative path without hostname/protocol, and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP v1.2 or 1.3 (yes they are deprecated - but hey someone might find this useful) you will need to add a Content-ID header to the image to be attached to the email so you can refer to it via the cid when using it inline in the message. Open the email controller of the cake installation and add this line in the __attachFiles() method:

$this->__message[] = 'Content-ID: <' . basename($file) . '>';

You can then add the image in your template like so:

The attachfile method of email class in v1.2 & 1.3 only accepts paths and does not have the added functionalities of later version hence the "hack"